# Loading image from ios assetlibrary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using following code to load image from assetlibrary. It's not working and if I click on displayImage uiimageviewer it shows invalid attempt to access  past the lifetime of its owning ALAssetsLibrary.

Header File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BFCropInterface.h"
#import "GRKImage.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface BFViewController : UIViewController{
    GRKImage *gImg;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *displayImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *originalImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) BFCropInterface *cropper;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GRKImage *gImg;
@property (strong, atomic) ALAssetsLibrary* library;

- (IBAction)cropPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)originalPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)savePressed:(id)sender;



@end
```

Main file : inside viewDidload

```
if ( [[self.gImg.URL absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"assets-library://"] ){


    typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
    typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset){

        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
        float scale=[rep scale];
        ALAssetOrientation orientation=[rep orientation];
        if (iref){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation];

                self.displayImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

                [self.displayImage setImage:originalImage];

            });


        }
    };

    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror){

        //failed to get image.
    };

    self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [self.library assetForURL:self.gImg.URL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently trying to use the `ALAssetRepresentation` `rep` on the main thread at which time the `assetslibrary` will have been released. Try either storing the `assetslibrary` as a property in the class or getting the `scale` and `orientation` outside of the block while the library is still valid.

---

You also shouldn't need to use `fullResolutionImage` if you're just displaying it. Use `fullScreenImage` instead.

Comment: I've added assetslibrary as property and synthesized it. But still getting same error.

Comment: Are you storing the library in the property?

Comment: Yes, I've added library as property. Added headerfile source in the question. Also as you've suggested I am calling scale and orientation outside of the block. Please check updated code. But still no result.

Comment: You should have no library error now then. Is `displayImage` set or is it nil?

Comment: I guess it's an outlet that you haven't connected.

Comment: No, I'm also loading remote images successfully in displayimage interface. Also now the code crashes. It says EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: IF I remove the threaded call, image load after waiting couple of minutes. Is it for large image size??

Comment: Does that mean you're creating multiple library instances? Consider turning on zombies too.

Comment: If I remove threaded call, now it's working perfectly well (except loading delay). I am using Alassetlibrary later on to save the image.

Comment: Turning on zombies how me the error: [Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11f639e0

Comment: Ok, try profiling in instruments and use the zombie type, should show you details so you can fix it

Comment: instruments points to UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation];

Comment: ok, move the UIImage generation out of the main thread block and just set the image into the view in the block